# C# Regex match only if not comment

Tags: c#, regex

I am writing an application for Avisynth-editing and try to get all variables which are defined as sources like the following ones with Regex:

```
Back = ImageReader("..\Backgrounds\Background_04.jpg", 0, Video.Framecount, 30, true).Spline16Resize(1920, 1080)

Video = ImageReader(".\Bilder\NDS Aufnahmebild.png", 0, 1000, 30, true)
```

I am using the following Regex which works great so far (global, case insensitive):

```
(?<var>[^#\s\t]\w+)(?:\s|\t)+?=(?:\s|\t)+?(ImageSource|ImageSourceAnim|ImageReader|ImageWriter)\((.*?)\)(?:\.|\n)?
```

The output would be:

Group "var" : Video

Group 0: ImageReader

Group 1: ".\Bilder\NDS Aufnahmebild.png", 0, 1000, 30, true

However it won't ignore comments which is really embarrasing. I want to capture the string only if there is no # before the match. I don't think that it's that complicated but at the moment I just don't get it.

I hope anybody can help me. I am using .Net Framework 4 and don't want to change the version.

Comment: Can you put a sample data and your expected output?

Comment: You may want to look in to Microsoft's upcomming [Rosyln](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis), Its CSharpSyntaxTree will make stuff like you are trying to do [a LOT easier](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/samples/csharp-semantic.pdf?raw=true).

Comment: I added information. I would have to change the framework version for RosyIn also I am writing an editor for Avisynth not C#. I also added the expected Output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as it is only `#` at beginning of the line, then you can simply try-match the `#` and then check if it actually did match it. If it didn't it is not commented, otherwise it is.

```
(?:\s|\t)*?(?<comment>#)?(?:\s|\t)*?(?<var>[^#\s\t]\w+)(?:\s|\t)+?=(?:\s|\t)+?(ImageSource|ImageSourceAnim|ImageReader|ImageWriter)\((.*?)\)(?:\.|\n)?
```

If `comment` group contains a `#`, then the line is commented out, so just ignore it in your application.

Comment: Oh that's a very simple solution but it does exactly what it should do. Thank you very much.